# How to make a DIV pop out from nowhere Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a game where I want to show two numbers. But I want these numbers to come out from nowhere, perhaps from the button of the screen and they travel up and then disappear.

I was looking through the Jquery website, but I couldn't find anything similar.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: not sure there's a function to location nowhere ;)

Comment: You can do that with simple CSS. But since you don't post any specifics, neither do I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres an example that i just wrote:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function(){
    $('.count').html(parseInt($('.count').html())+1);

    //allow time for animation to finish before next click
    $('button').hide();
    window.setTimeout(function(){$('button').show();},3000); 

    $("div").css("bottom","-20px");
    $("div").animate({bottom: '1200px'}, 2000);
  })
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xop36gcs/4/